# Configure UniCastBus in NServiceBus using IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized

Tags: nservicebus

I would like to "hook in" and tweak configuration to `UnicastBus` and was looking at doing this using `IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized`.

I would like to tweak/set the value for: `ForwardReceivedMessagesTo`. Any ideas on how that should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately due to a bug (see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1960), the only possible way is to programmatically replace the whole `UnicastBusConfig`, eg:

```
class Foo : IProvideConfiguration<UnicastBusConfig>
{
    public UnicastBusConfig GetConfiguration()
    {
        var unicastBusConfig = new UnicastBusConfig
        {
            ForwardReceivedMessagesTo = "FooBar",
        };
        unicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection();
        unicastBusConfig.MessageEndpointMappings.Add(...);

        return unicastBusConfig;
    }
}
```

But that is quite ugly :(